# How to avoid including authors in second page for a document with two title pages using authblk package

Tags: titles, authblk

I have a document with two title pages. In the first I need to include the authors with footnote for the corresponding author using `\thanks` but in the second one only include the title and abstract. However, I have not been able because in the second title page the same authors and footnote from the first page appears in the second one. I tried to include `\author{\emptythanks}` but the following error is displayed:

```
 ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. \@footnotetext
#1->\insert \footins
```

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openbib]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\date{  }
\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[2]{Author 2\thanks{Corresponding author}}
\affil[1]{University 1}
\affil[2]{University 2}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\title{Title}
\date{  }
\author{\emptythanks}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}

The Abstract

\end{abstract}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here: one is where `\emptythanks` goes, and the other is that there is a clash between the packages `titling` and `authblk`. A quick hack to get what you want is

```
\documentclass[12pt,openbib]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Redefine \emptythanks to do what we want, by stopping \thanks
% from doing anything and getting rid of the thanks already stored

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\emptythanks}{%
\renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\@thanks}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\date{  }
\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[2]{Author 2\thanks{Corresponding author}}
\affil[1]{University 1}
\affil[2]{University 2}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

%\title{Title}
%\date{  }
\emptythanks

% You don't need to repeat the title, and this is where \emptythanks would go

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}

The Abstract

\end{abstract}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for the footnote. However, I was not clear before and I need also to not include the authors and affiliations in the second page. How could I do that?

Comment: I included
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\emptyauthor}{%
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\@author}{}}
\makeatother

and in the second title page include \emptyauthor

and it seems to works

Comment: Yep, that'll do it ... although in your code you don't need to change the `\author` command, just `\@author`. The former adds a new author, the latter is the list of authors.